# can xampp and net beans can work together for tomcat

Tags: java, mysql, xampp, tomcat7, netbeans-7

I have installed xampp on my system and now I want to install netbeans 7.4 in my system to use the tomcat service from xampp

I want to do the rest of my coding in netbeans. Is this possible? If yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

you should download the netbeans which has Apache Tomcat included in the installer (eg. Full version 210MB ), then select to install tomcat in the netbeans installer.

Open the netbeans project, change the web container of the project to tomcat, and save and run your project.

if you cannot find tomcat in netbeans, make sure you installed the tomcat using the netbeans installer
if you cannot start tomcat in netbeans, make sure your tomcat is not started in xampp.